# Can I use SQL Server Enterprise Edition on VM Azure for production use

Tags: sql-server, hosting, azure, licensing, sql-server-2014

I have Microsoft BizSpark subscription in which I received Azure credits as well. I created a Virtual machine on it and I am planning to install SQL Server Enterprise edition which I see available under Subscriber downloads page. Can I install it on my VM and host a website using this.

[image]
[image]

Can I also create users with sql authentication and assign them to multiple people in my team for making changes in sql script or do any development activities. Is it allowed?

Comment: Define "Website". The purpose counts - development, testing, demo is ok (that is what development software is for). Production is not.

Comment: @TomTom Can I host my company website on it? Once I am done with Demo, how can I sell developed product? Do I need to purchase another Visual Studio license for deploying on to production?

Comment: A little bit common sense please. A company website OBVIOUSLY is not development and testing. And you seem to be totally unaware about the deployment tools coming with visual studio. Create an installer and redistributing the resitributables from VS is part of development.

Comment: @TomTom, I am unaware of deployment tools. What my goal is to create web api services and host them on IIS along with angularjs based html pages on IIS. As I will be publishing this so that source files are generated as dll wherever applicable, can I host resulting webservice files on any server for production use. There won't be any redistributable

Comment: Well, a read through the basics of how .NET works is in order, you know. Not an admin question - you are confused even on a beginner developer level.

Comment: @TomTom - I think your comments are a bit harsh here. This is an Azure licensing question. Not a .net question, not a Visual Studio question. Not a place to tell someone to have "A little bit common sense please." A company website can, and should, be developed and tested using all tools available. There are ways to then purchase production licenses after graduating from BizSpark. Whether it's best posted in ServerFault is beside the point.

Answer (score 0):

Nop. From the FAQs

> BizSpark members receive access to Not-For-Resale software versions
>   equivalent to those included in the Visual Studio Ultimate with
>   Microsoft Developer Network subscription. **BizSpark software is for
>   design, development, test, and demo only**. For the most up to date
>   listing of these products click products by benefit level and then
>   click Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN tab for a representative list
>   of products.

https://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/faqs.aspx